# Firebase know when message pushed?

Tags: image, upload, firebase

I'm upload images in the form of Base64 into Firebase but what I've noticed is that it shows up on the uploader's interface before it's finished uploading to Firebase server.

So how would I know when it's finished uploading the image?

Alternatively, how can I postpone the image showing up on the uploader's interface until the image has been uploaded, so it displays synchronously with all users?

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Edit: March 6th

Ok so I've reduce the code to the bare minimum to demonstrate this. Though to observe this effect it's best to view the [**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/FlyingEmu/pen/MYqwxE) on two separate locations simultaneously.

**HTML:**

```
<script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.0.4/firebase.js'></script>
<ul id="messages"></ul>
<input id="upload" type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="uploadImage()">
```

**JQuery:**

```
var dataRef = new Firebase('https://citruso.firebaseio.com/');
var messagesRef = dataRef.child('Messages');

messagesRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
  var message = snapshot.val();
  var text = message.text;
  if (text.substring(0,11) === "data:image/") {
    $('#messages').append('<img class="message-image" src="' + text + '">');
  }
  else {
    $('#messages').append('<li>' + text + '</li>');
  }
});

function uploadImage() {
  var file = document.querySelector('#upload').files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onloadend = function () {
    messagesRef.push({text: reader.result});
  }
  if (file) {
    if (file.size < 10000000) {
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
    else {
      alert('File size cannot exceed 10mb.');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think Firebase notifications fire for partial data. Can you show a minimal piece of code that reproduces your problem?

Comment: The client libraries all expose completion callbacks for when a message has been acknowledged by the server. If you post some code, we can see if you're using it effectively.

Comment: Thanks Frank & Rob for the replies, I've edited the question to include the necessary code.